# Nested data access calls with spring webflux-reactor

Tags: spring-data, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am trying to do a nested calls to database, using spring webflux/reactor, to return a Mono of nested objects (a User with his Roles).

The scenario is as following:

- retrieve a user row having a username from database;
- map the user row to User POJO;
- retrieve roles of the user by user id;
- map roles to List of Roles;
- set the mapped roles to User POJO;
- return a Mono of User.

The scenario above have to be done without blocking (I know that the mapping is a so little blocking :) ).

```
public Mono<User> retrieveByUsername(String username)  {
    return databaseClient.execute(usersQueries.getProperty("users.select.by.username"))
            .bind("username", username.toLowerCase())
            .map((row, meta) -> UserRowMapper.mapRow(row, meta))
            // here goes nested database query to retrieve roles and set them to retrieved user 
            // and return Mono<User>
            .one();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use flatmap, then do your next call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I see a solution for your question:

```
public Mono<User> retrieveByUsername(String username) {
    Mono<User> userMono = databaseClient
            .execute(usersQueries.getProperty("users.select.by.username"))
            .<User>map((row, meta) -> UserRowMapper.mapRow(row, meta))
            .one()
            .cache();

    Flux<Role> roles = Mono
            .from(userMono)
            .flatMapMany(user -> databaseClient
                    .execute(usersQueries.getProperty("roles.select.by.user.id"))
                    .bind("userId", user.getId())
                    .<Role>map((row, meta) -> RoleRowMapper.mapRow(row, meta))
                    .all()
            );

    return Mono
            .from(userMono)
            .flatMap(user -> roles
                    .collectList()
                    .map(r -> {
                        user.setRoles(r);
                        return user;
                    })
            );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stepan. That's  what I need exactly.

Comment: I’m glad that was helpful!